# Hypothesis testing on Poisson Binomial distribution

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, multiple-comparisons, poisson-binomial-distribution

Imagine $N$ baskets each filled with a different number of products chosen from a set $P$. It is possible to have repeated products in the same basket.

For instance:

```
basket 1 = [A,B,B,C]
basket 2 = [A,B,C,D,F,J]
basket 3 = [C]
...
basket N = [E,E,E,F,F]
```

Now we ask someone to chose one item from every basket. For instance:

```
basket 1 = [A,B,B,C] - A
basket 2 = [A,B,C,D,F,J] - A
basket 3 = [C] - C
...
basket N = [A,E,E,E,F,F] - E
```

How can we test the preference of this person for a given product?

**EDIT**:

The problem can be simplified into this one:

We have $N$ independent trials where every trial $i$ follows a Bernoulli distribution with probability $p_i$. That is, a Poisson Binomial distribution.

Imagine that we observed $k$ successful trials.

Is there a way to compute the deviation of the observation respect to the distribution, and how significant is that deviation?

(I'm thinking of p-values and z-scores in a normal distribution)

Comment: When you say 'test the preference' what do you mean exactly? Are you testing some hypothesis? What hypothesis is that?

Comment: Actually the thing is that I'm not sure how to formulate the hypothesis.

In layman words, if the items are food and the person is hungry, she will first observe what is available and then will make a choice. I guess that we could formally express this as P(A)>P(B), P(A)>P(C)...

However, I would like to plot something like the z-score and the p-value for every item (currently I sum up all the choices and plot the histogram, which is really pointless since it does not take into acount the probability that every choice had)

Comment: It's really unclear to me what specific problem you want solved. The stackexchange model isn't particularly suited to situations where you're very unclear about what you want to do. Does the word 'test' even apply? Can you perhaps formulate the kinds of things you want to ask of the data in plain English (preferably avoiding statistical jargon like 'test' altogether)?

Comment: In other words, 'test the preference' = the probability distribution of choices is not random uniform, but multinomial with more probability on some of the products. Maybe to simplify the problem we can consider that many choices can be made from the same basket. Maybe this way I could have like M bernouilli trials of e.g. A, each with a different probability (1/4, 1/6, 0...1/6) and check that choices of $A$ (A=True) are higher than expected.

Comment: @Glen_b I edited the question and simplified (I hope!) the problem.

Comment: Quite a different question, but much clearer and easily answered.

Comment: :-) Now I found that Poisson Binomial distribution is not trivial at all, but that it might be approximated to a Poisson. And from a Poisson, I can easily compute where the alphas are to asses the significance of my observations (only 1 observation for every poisson :().

Comment: The Poisson only applies in some cases. The normal approximation may apply also (widening the range of possible cases where you can do something very simple), but there's always simulation, and that's even easier, really (at least it is if you have something like R, and a computer).

Comment: maybe this can help (section 3) http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/160458/estimate-accuracy-of-an-estimation-on-poisson-binomial-distribution/164746#164746

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just use the number of successes itself as the test statistic.

If you want a one-tailed test this is simple (and I expect you will). For a two tailed test, because of the asymmetry, the usual approach would be to allocate $\alpha/2$ to each tail and compute a rejection region that way. There's some variation in exactly how this gets implemented since you can't get exactly $\alpha/2$ in either tail, but p-values are slightly complicated (you base them on whatever rules you come up with for how your rejection region would actually be computed).

1) If the $p_i$s are known and all are small, you can use a Poisson approximation for the number of successes.

If the p's are all pretty small, the mean of the sum is close to the variance of the sum, so one quick assessment of whether they're small enough is to compare the variance to the mean; if it's pretty close, this will normally work fairly well. What constitutes 'close' depends on your criteria, you really need to calibrate it yourself. As a very rough rule of thumb I'd suggest variance/mean above 0.9, but you may want it higher. If you want a more precise rule about when the Poisson will work, [Le Cam's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Cam%27s_theorem) bounds the sum of absolute deviations between the true probability function and the Poisson approximation (though this doesn't necessarily tell you how well it performs in the part of the tail that determines the accuracy of a nominal significance level).

2) If the $p_i$ are not necessarily small but there are a lot of them you can use a normal approximation (perhaps with continuity correction). Assuming the p's are typically less than 0.5, a simple rule would be if the coefficient of variation for the number of successes is sufficiently* small, the normal approximation should be fine.

* what constitutes 'sufficiently' depends on your criteria, again, you really need to calibrate it yourself. But as a very rough rule of thumb, I'd suggest that the reciprocal of the coefficient of variation should be more than 4 if you want roughly accurate p-values around 0.05 (one tailed), more than 5 if you want roughly accurate p-values around the 2.5% level, and more than 7 if you want reasonable accuracy around the 1% level. Those are pretty rough, though, you may well want more accuracy than that.

3) If there's very little variation in the $p_i$'s, you could use a binomial approximation.

4) You can simulate the distribution of the number of successes directly.

5) The probability function for the convolution of the Bernoulli($p_i$) variables is fairly easy to compute numerically. For small numbers of variables (up to a couple of dozen easily), it can be done by brute force with no difficulty. [For large numbers, you're probably better off using FFT, as it's much faster, though you'll likely hit the point where normal approximation is very accurate long before it's much of an issue.]

In each of the cases (1) to (3),  you can check the quality of the approximation via simulation... but if you do that, you might as well get the p-value the same way.

Incidentally, the R package `poibin` offers four calculations or approximations (it does not include the Poisson). There's an associated paper

Hong, Y. (2012),
"On computing the distribution function for the Poisson binomial distribution."
*Computational Statistics & Data Analysis.*
http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.csda.2012.10.006.  (Tech Report [here](http://www.web-e.stat.vt.edu/dept/web-e/tech_reports/Technical_Report_11_2.pdf))

where the author derives an expression based on the discrete Fourier transform.

---

Here's an example, using the Poisson approximation:

$p_1, ..., p_5 = 0.05, p_6, ...,p_9 = 0.10$

The mean is 0.65 and the standard deviation = $\sqrt{0.05\times 0.95\times 5 + 0.10 \times 0.90 \times 4} \approx 0.773$

The coefficient of variation rules out the normal approximation. The variance divided by the mean is 0.92, which suggests the Poisson may not do too badly.

The possible (typical range) one tailed significance levels for a Poisson(0.65) are 13.8%, 2.8%, 0.44% ... Let's say we choose 2.8%, which is to say if we see 3 or more successes we'll reject the null.

Now, the exact calculation is simply the convolution of a Binomial(5,0.05) and a Binomial(4,0.10), and this immediately is:

```
             0         1         2         3         4         5        6       7 ... 
exact 0.5076777 0.3592339 0.1110464 0.0196723 0.0022006 0.0001612 7.70e-06 2.0e-07  
Pois  0.5220458 0.3393298 0.1102822 0.0238945 0.0038829 0.0005048 5.47e-05 5.1e-06
```

As you see they're at least close-ish except in the far tail (up to X=3 say); the exact significance level for a rejection rule of 'reject if there are at least 3 successes' is about 2.2%, while the Poisson gave about 2.8%. For my purposes that would be reasonable, but your own needs may differ.

Comment: Thanks @Glen_b ! In my case, $p_{i}$ might change a lot, and even if the properties of smallness and low variance hold for one item, they might be completely different for another (items= triads (graphs) in forum threads, and success = user participates in that triad)...

Comment: ...Thus, I think a simulation (4) would be the best choice. So, if I understood correctly, for every item, I run a Monte Carlo simulation according to its known probabilities $p_i$. Then, I compute the p-values by counting the number of times that my observation is higher / lower than the simulated statistic. ($p_{upper} = \frac{n_{greater}+1}{n_{runs}+1}$)

Comment: Yes. you can do it essentially that way. However, numerical convolution may be faster unless your dimension of $p$ is very large. Since you posted, I have found various other papers with various expressions or approximations but I haven't had time to review them.

Comment: I am implementing the Monte Carlo sampler and one question arose to which I don't find a clear answer anywhere: how many samples do I need? :-O

Comment: That depends on the accuracy you want in your p-values! I often regard 10,000 as a minimum - near the 5% level, the standard error in the estimated type I error rate for a given critical value is $\sqrt{0.05\times 0.95/10000}=0.0022$, meaning we should be within about $0.005$ of the correct rejection rate; I often do more - sometimes many more if I need to construct a table or something, sometimes fewer if I am not fussy about my actual rejection rate (not doing a formal test, for example). It's not unusual for me to do a million simulations if it's fast. I use small runs (~100) to time &debug

Comment: I have like 100k users and about 10 distributions per user = 1000000 p-values to compute. I could sacrifice some accuracy since it is only a preliminary phase (I will eventually cluster users with similar distributions, so the "real" validation will have to be there). Anyway, thanks for your clear explanations (and for your patience!)

Comment: maybe this will help (section 3) http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/160458/estimate-accuracy-of-an-estimation-on-poisson-binomial-distribution/164746#164746